# Error al subir page React.js a repositorio Git

Tags: reactjs, github

Estoy tratando de subir un proyecto de React.js a un repositorio de Github, y cuando lo quiero abrir desde Git no me aparece la carpeta **src** con todo el contenido de la page que cree y al abrirlo se ve todo en blanco y en consola este error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Probé cambiar desde el **`package.json`** el *private* a "*false*" pensando que podía ser eso pero al parecer no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La documentación de create-react-app explica cómo deployar a github pages:

[Doc. GitHub Pages](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages)

Esta es la información más importante (si no configura esto antes de crear su aplicación, no funcionará):
Open your package.json and add a homepage field for your project:

> Abra su paquete.json y agregue un campo de página de inicio para su
> proyecto:
>
> `"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app"`,
>
> Create React App usa el campo de la página de inicio para determinar la URL
> raíz en el archivo HTML creado.

Esto también podría ser relevante para su aplicación:

[Serving the Same Build from Different Paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths)